# TypeError: ufunc 'true_divide' output (typecode 'd') could not be coerced to provided output parameter (typecode 'q')

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I am trying to apply Gower distance implementation to my data frame. While it was smoothly working with the same dataset with more features, this time it gives an error when I call the Gower distance function. I import the Gower's function from another .py code in the same directory. Here is my code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

import gower_function as gf

# Importing the dataset with pandas
dataset = pd.read_excel('input_partial.xlsx')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:].values
df = pd.DataFrame(X)
#obtaining gower distances of instances
Gower = gf.gower_distances(X)
```

and after executing this, I got the error below:

```
File "<ipython-input-10-6a4c39600b0e>", line 1, in <module>
Gower = gf.gower_distances(X)

File "C:\Users\...\Clustering\Section 24 - K-Means 
Clustering\gower_function.py", line 184, in gower_distances
X_num = np.divide(X_num ,max_of_numeric,out=np.zeros_like(X_num), 
where=max_of_numeric!=0)

TypeError: ufunc 'true_divide' output (typecode 'd') could not be coerced to 
provided output parameter (typecode 'q') according to the casting rule 
''same_kind''
```

I did not understand how it can give this error on the same dataset with only fewer features (columns). Is there anyone who can recognize the reason?

Comment: Are you sure that the types of `df` are what you expect? What does `print(df.dtypes)` yield?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue. It seems that if all of your variables are integers, then it produces this error. So I have changed every integer column to string values.

```
cluster_data = cluster_data.astype(str)
cluster_data.dtypes.head()
```

This seems to fix the error.

Answer (score 11):

You need to specify `dtype` of the left operand to be non integer, some floating point type, e.g.

```
a = np.array(..., dtype=float)
np.divide(a, b, out=np.zeros_like(a), where=(b!=0))
```

If `dtype` of `a` and `b` are both integers, then the error you get is: **No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc true_divide**.

If `dtype` of `a` is integer but `b` - float, then the error you get is: **ufunc 'true_divide' output (typecode 'd') could not be coerced to provided output parameter (typecode 'l') according to the casting rule ''same_kind''**.

Answer (score 1):

`np.zeros_like(a)` creates an array with the same dtype as `a`. So if `a` is int dtype and the numpy operation that it is used as `out=` (e.g. `np.divide`, `np.log`, `np.exp` etc.) must produce a float array, the dtypes won't match; hence the error. One way to get around the issue is to use `np.zeros(a.shape)` instead.

```py
a = b = np.random.default_rng().choice(10, size=1000000)
np.divide(a, b, out=np.zeros_like(a), where=b!=0)       # UFuncTypeError
np.divide(a, b, out=np.zeros(a.shape), where=b!=0)      # OK
```

or change dtype of the array passed to `zeros_like` into float (as suggested by Dan Oak).

```py
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:].values.astype(float)
```